# Implementing native social authentication flow with react-native and a backend API

Tags: node.js, react-native, authentication, google-authentication, facebook-authentication

I am developing a mobile application and am using React Native with a NodeJS / MongoDB API Backend.
I would like to add social authentication (Google/Facebook) to my application. 
It is also important to me that the social authentication happens as a Native Login flow and not browser based (i.e. the user is not redirected to the browser to enter his/her credentials).
I also want to have some token returned whenever the user authenticates with either Google or Facebook so that I can use the token to call my API, verify that the token is correct and return user specific resources.

Most examples that I found use Firebase but I prefer not using Firebase since I am already using MongoDB. Other examples implement a WebView thus the user is redirected to the corresponding social provider via the browser and I also don't want that since I want to provide a Native experience.

I am also thinking to try and use one of the following libraries: https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth or https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth to implement this.

I am looking for any help/suggestions on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook, use [react-native-fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk).

For Google, use [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin).

Both do not redirect to browsers for login and have tokens should you need to use them.